# Is there a Java library to validate that an XML snippet is a subset of a larger XML file?

Tags: java, xml, comparison

I'm looking for code which can do the following.  Given a snippet of XML, say:

```
<c>Some text</c>
```

and a complete XML file:

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c>Some text</c>
   </b>
</a>
```

check that the snippet is indeed a valid subset of the complete XML file.  I've been looking at [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) which looks really good, but it seems to only validate complete files against each other.

For the sample above, a simple string comparison would work, but other features I would like to support might be:

1) Order of child elements not important.  E.g.

```
<b>
   <c>Some text</c>
   <d>Other text</d>
</b>
```

is a valid subset of

```
<a>
   <b>
      <d>Other text</d>
      <c>Some text</c>
   </b>
</a>
```

2) Ignore whitespace, tabs, new lines etc.
3) A nice to have would be XMLUnit's skeleton feature where node names and structure are checked, but not content values.  E.g. `<c>Some text</c>` would be valid when compared against `<c>Other text</c>`.

Comment: Why not use `xpath.evaluate()` function for evaluation?

Comment: XML is an hierarchical structure, so each valid XML fragment can be interpreted as full XML document. I do not see any problem to run any kind of XML validation against your fragment <c>foo</c>.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - Could you expand?  And could it be tweaked to meet points 1, 2 and 3 above?

Comment: @AlexR perhaps I misunderstand your comment, but I'm not looking to validate the snippets, just check whether or not they are a subset of a larger document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's such a library but you could solve it in the following way (if your xml fragment starts with an element). I assume you are familiar with XMLUnit.

```
public boolean isSubset(Document document, Element element) {
    NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName(element.getNodeName());
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        Element el = (Element) list.item(i);
        Document clone = toNewDocument(el);
        //compare element with clone with XMLUnit
        //...
        if (equal) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private Document toNewDocument(Element el) {
    // createing a new DOM-document...
    Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
    Node node = document.importNode(el, true);
    document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(node);
    return document;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dmitry747, this looks really good.  I'll give it a try.